# getting / setting values from divs

Tags: jquery

I am having 2 divs:

```
<div id="1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>

<div id="2">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

How would you get/set the First Name and Last Name for the div number, div 1 or 2 ?

Thanks

Comment: `id`'s must start with a letter, A-Z, a-z. For future reference.

Comment: Both submit buttons will send the same data, two arrays of FirstName and LastName.

Comment: Correcting myself: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute - in HTML5, `id`'s can now have any value (so long as there are no spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` and `val`:

```
// Get
var firstName = $("#1").find("[name='FirstName']").val();

// Set
$("#1").find("[name='LastName']").val("New Last Name");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EknLw/